# How to get scroller scroll contents of my viewGroup

Tags: android, view

hello
I've tried hardly to get scroller scroll contents of my viewGroup but i failed
my code is someting like

```
    maxY = getChildCount() * getChildAt(0).getHeight();
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        Log.v("log_trace", "Asd50Act.AsdView.onFling()");
        scroller.fling(0, Math.round(e1.getY()), 0, Math.round(velocityY),
                0, 0, 0, maxY);
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
```

sure I've initialized scroller & gestureDetector
scrollBy() works fine
any help??

Comment: OK i got it scroller calculate scroll according to time not do actual scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Nevertheless you could share your idea with others who are looking for some help. Here is how it works: You simply need to call `scroller.computeScrollOffset()` directly before getting the current x and y values.